# Redmi 9T stuck in fastboot mode after flashing recovery

Tags: adb, rooting, recovery-mode, fastboot, xiaomi

I decided to root my phone, but after rebooting into **Fastboot via adb**, I was a little wary, because I noticed not **Fastboot, but FastbootD**, but even scored on it, because it was detected through `fastboot devices`. I wrote all the necessary commands for flashing the **recovery partition**, everything seemed to be successful, but after writing `fastboot reboot`, the phone got **stuck** in fastboot mode. Like, no matter how much you reboot or flash it - **it literally** **doesn't care, it reboots back to fastboot mode**. Also, after several such reboots, fastboot began to issue as many **as two devices** when trying to find them, and you have to execute it through the `-s` operand in order for the commands to be used. In addition, there was a delay in the region of two to three seconds before the command was executed.
What to do about it? Reflash via `flash-all.bat` in the firmware archive, or is it possible to restore it without it?[image]

Comment: restart PC and try *'fastboot continue'* or flash stock recovery

Comment: Thanks, but I already solved the problem: it was enough to reset the phone via fastboot firmware, and then download the firmware for installation via recovery, and, after installing the correct recovery image, flash the phone from there